# Selenium, understanding xPath; Input vs Select; cycle through elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

On the webpage I am wroking, I might encounter two types of input fields (depending on the situation) - it will be either select or input, with the following example xPath:

Case Select

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[20]/td[3]/div/select
```

Case Input

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[19]/td[3]/div/input
```

because I don't know what will be the field type, I am going to use following sytnax:

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[20]/td[3]/div/*
```

1. As I understand, when I use selenium driver.find_element_by_xpath, with "*" example of the path, code will return me first element which matches the criteria? 
   How can I use something like "find next"?
2. How can I distinguish between Input and Select field? 
   I tried the following:

- obj.get_attribute("type") -> returns "text"
- obj.get_attribute("class") -> returns "form-control variant-value variant1"
- obj.get_attribute("//xpath@class") -> returns "None"
- obj.tag_name - returns "input"
- ob.text -> returns "" 
   
  I would expect return like "Select" or "Input". 
  Where can I find documentation related to what can I write inside "get_attribute"?

   
  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**First question :**

As I understand, when I use selenium `driver.find_element_by_xpath`, with "*" example of the path, code will return me first element which matches the criteria?
How can I use something like "find next"?

**Ans :** yes it will return the first element, in case you want all of them, switch to `find_elements`. for this `How can I use something like "find next"?` - what do you mean by next ? - I would assume that as a next sibling, if that is the case then you can make use of `::followin-sibling`

**2nd Question :**

```
How can I distinguish between Input and Select field?
```

pretty simple with the xpath :-

```
//input
```

to select all input, you can have it like `//input[attribute_name='attribute_value']` to distinguish b/w input fields.

and

```
//select
```

and can use it more constructive like :

```
//select[attribute_name='attribute_value']
```

Now,

```
I would expect return like "Select" or "Input".
```

you can use `tag_name`, like below :-

```
obj.tag_name
```

print this and you should get the tag name appropriate.

```
Where can I find documentation related to what can I write inside "get_attribute"?
```

`get_attribute` is to fetch attribute value, for the specified web element -> attribute name.

This is what officials says :

> get_attribute(name) Gets the given attribute or property of the
> element.
>
> This method will first try to return the value of a property with the
> given name. If a property with that name doesn’t exist, it returns the
> value of the attribute with the same name. If there’s no attribute
> with that name, None is returned.
>
> Values which are considered truthy, that is equals “true” or “false”,
> are returned as booleans. All other non-None values are returned as
> strings. For attributes or properties which do not exist, None is
> returned.

Find the official document here for [get_attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Comment: 1) How do I use ```::followin-sibling```
2) One time the Input might be regular one *\Input the other time it might be *\Select. Is there anyway I can identfity if the element I found is Input or Select? ```obj.tag_name``` always return "input", it's like it does not see difference

Comment: How do I use ::followin-sibling, this is basically xpath axes, see here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp,  `obj.tag_name always return "input", it's like it does not see difference` this depends on your xpath, what xpath did you pass ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath` you can use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`.
   This will give you all the elements matching the passed locator, so in your case

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your_xpath")
```

`elements[0]` will give you the first element matching `your_xpath` while the second element matching the `your_xpath` locator will be `elements[1]`
2) to get already selected element's tag name you can use `obj.tag_name` method.
To select the desired element explicitly you can mention it's tag name in your XPath locator so the selected element WILL be of desired type.
You can use something like `//*parent_elements//select` to get the Select element and correspondingly `//*parent_elements//input` to get the input element.
As for the `get_attribute` method - cruisepandey already referred you to the documentation. I just want to clarify, that attributes are not including tag name. So, tag name is not an attribute property of the element.

Comment: Is there any way I can check if from ```find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[20]/td[3]/div/*")``` I receive *\Input or *\Select?